# onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu) is not being invoked after pressing the back button

Tags: android

I am trying to invoked the `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` in the MainActivity after pressing the back button in the Map activity but it is not being invoked after it was created once.
According to the documentation it must be called right before the menu is shown.
Is this case valid after invoking  the onBackPressed()?

> Prepare the Screen's standard options menu to be displayed. This is called right before the menu is shown, every time it is shown. You can use this method to efficiently enable/disable items or otherwise dynamically modify the contents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yea you can just add this in your activity. This will make it be called anytime you come back from any activity though.

```
@Override
public void OnStart()
{
   super.onStart();
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

Comment: And what about the Parameter Menu menu since I am getting `The method onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu) in the type MainActivity is not applicable for the arguments ()`?

Answer (score 1):

This is how create and prepare works for menu

`onCreateOptionsMenu()` called only once when the Activity or Fragment is created

`onPrepareOptionsMenu()` usually used for some dynamic control contents

In order to `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` to be triggered you have to call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`